# Get all SVN property names and values with single command

Tags: svn

I have already written code that `proplist`s against a URL and then loops over the results `propget`ing to acquire all the properties.  I have two issues with this approach is:

1. It takes a separate SVN call for `proplist` and then another `propget` call for each set property.
2. It involves placing an uncontrolled string from `proplist` on the command lines for `propget`.

While the second could presumably be addressed by checking/cleansing/protecting against the string, the first can only be addressed by using a single command.

**Is there a single SVN command command which can get all property names and value for a given URL?**

This is not a request for recursive properties of all subdirectories and files, nor is it a request for all properties of an object throughout it's history.  Just for that single object at a single specified revision.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds to me like you want use the `-v` option to `svn proplist`.  For example:

```
svn proplist -v -r 1553386 https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/tools/dev
```

Which produces:

> Properties on
>   'https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/tools/dev':
>   svn:ignore
>       .libs
>       fsfs-access-map
>       logdata.py

If you run the same command with for revision 1553385 you'll get different output since the fsfs-reorg was removed the the svn:ignore property there.  If you're trying to parse this I strongly suggest using the `--xml` option because the default "human friendly" output is not really something you can parse.

Comment: Looks good and it's right there in the help if I bothered to read `--verbose`.  *shakes head*  I agree with the ``--xml`` recommendation though in this case there was existing diff parsing in the project which made my cheater solution work well.  Also, the diff provides some level of parsability based on the `+`/`-` prefixes.  Long term I agree it would be better for the project to move to exclusive XML output.  Thanks!

Comment: A better option would be to switch to bindings and then not parse the command line client at all.  I didn't mention it since it was clear you had an existing project that was already doing parsing and I have no idea what language you're using, which might not have bindings.

Answer (score 1):

By `diff`ing against @0 the data is all provided though formatted as a diff which will require stripping of leading `+`...  except when it is missing for some reason such as with `svn:mergeinfo`.

```
$ svn diff --properties-only -r'0':'42' --depth empty 'http://server.domain.name/svn/repo_name/path/in/repo@42'

Index: .
===================================================================
--- .   (revision 0)
+++ .   (revision 42)

Property changes on: .
___________________________________________________________________
Added: svn:externals
## -0,0 +1,2 ##
+^/../repo1_name/path/in/repo@11 libs/repo1
+^/../repo2_name/path/in/repo@13 libs/repo2
Added: svn:mergeinfo
   Merged /path/in/repo:r17-23
   Merged /path/in/branch:r5-11
Added: svn:ignore
## -0,0 +1,2 ##
+result
+temp
```

This is helpful but not quite as direct as I would like...